# getting exceptions using cloudrail AdvancedRequest

Tags: .net, cloudrail

I am trying to use the advanced request in my .NET project, and get an exception

System.SystemException: 'ServiceCode Error in function AdvancedRequestSupporter:advancedRequest at 11: http.requestCall $L1 $L0 ’

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type ‘System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Object]’.

code:
        AdvancedRequestSpecification req = new AdvancedRequestSpecification("/pubapi/v1/properties/namespace");
        req.SetMethod(“POST”);
        Dictionary body = new Dictionary();
        body[“test”] =55;
        req.SetBodyStringifyJson(body) ;

```
    // Specify the headers            
    Dictionary<String, string> headers = new Dictionary<String, string>();
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    req.SetHeaders(headers);

    AdvancedRequestResponse res = AdvancedRequest(req);
```

i get this exception even if i dont set the body or the header

so something like
AdvancedRequestSpecification req = new AdvancedRequestSpecification("/pubapi/v1/properties/namespace");
req.SetMethod(“POST”);
AdvancedRequestResponse res = AdvancedRequest(req);

can anyone help? i forgot to mention that i tried with Box and egynte

Answer (score 0):

I've decompiled your dll and found the problem, the AdvancedRequestSpecification has a Dictionary(String, string) headers properties, whilst your RequestCall.Execute() casts the headers variable directly to a      Dictionary(string,object) which won't work, I've change the AdvancedRequestSpecification header property to be a Dictionary and it is now working,

So my worry is that from a customer point of view I can't see how this code has been tested at all which doesn't inspire confidence in your library

Also the lack of response from you guys either through this forum, the support ticket, or stackoverflow makes me want to not use this at all.